# Why my permissions for firestore don't work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**My code**

```
created(){
let ref = db.collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp')

// subscribe to changes to the 'messages' collection
ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {

  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if(change.type == 'added'){
      let doc = change.doc
      this.messages.push({
        id: doc.id,
        name: doc.data().name,
        content: doc.data().content,
        timestamp: moment(doc.data().timestamp).format('lll')
      })
    }
  })
})
```

**My rules for firebase:**

```
service cloud.firestore { match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /messages/{document=**} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
 }
}}
```

**My error**

> Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient
>   permissions.

help solve the problem

Comment: Are you logged in or authenticated? This error occurs due to your rule `allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid`, which blocks your request.

Comment: i tried this one, same issue :  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if false;
      }
   }
}

Comment: ups it actually working

Comment: Are you sure that `this.messages`represents the `messages` collection?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) from the docs.

You're only allowing read operations that satisfy `request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid`, but you're trying to read the whole `db.collection('messages')` collection.

Try reading `db.collection('messages').where('uid', '==', currentUserUid)`.

(And don't forget to actually put a `uid` property in messages.)

---

PS: Your rules look like they're for personal notes, not messages between users. If you want the recipients to be different than the authors, you will have to change your data structure and rules. Maybe with `authorUid` and `recipientUid` fields, I don't know, I haven't done anything similar in Firestore yet.